# Multiple or single controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-web

What is the ratio in defining multiple controllers (in Spring MVC) instead of just one that matches all paths?
Could you write me also a use case scenario?

Comment: I think it is better to follow single responsibility principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Lyju, the number of Controller in a Spring MVC application is a personal choice, but it is better to follow the single responsability principle: **every module should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software**.

For furhter details:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle